# Passing URL parameters to APP_CONTROLLER?

Tags: cakephp-1.3

I am writing my multilevel navigation element(s), data coming from database. When I click menu item, I want to pass parameter to APP_CONTROLLER, which would do some magic for me.

How can I pass URL parameters to APP_CONTROLLER to have functionality, that would affect on all controllers?

URL: http://localhost/controller/function/id:5 or http://localhost/controller/function/5

If I try to fetch parameter(s) in APP_CONTROLLER like this

public function beforeFilter() {

$id = $this->params['id']; 
} }

or

public function beforeFilter($id) {

some code

}}

I will get error messages like **Undefined index...** or  **Missing argument 1 for AppController::beforeFilter()...**

I am pretty new to CakePHP, how this can be done? Or have I some fundamendal design flaw?

// Jari

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first option is better.

app_controller

```
public function beforeFilter() {
   $id = $this->params['id'];
}
```

view

```
$this->Html->link(__("menu 1",true), array('id'=>'1');
```

And do not forget to add "parent::beforeFilter();" in within "beforeFilter" at other Controllers.

I hope you help.